# Magento 2: Can i add wishlist and compare buttons for algolia search result page product items

Tags: magento2, algolia, algolia-search

i need to add wish list and compare buttons to each products on search result page same as magento category pages

Comment: Magento already provides this functionality. https://tinyurl.com/28c2u6c4

Comment: @RonakRathod yes. magento already provides the add to wishlist and compare functionality. but when i use algolia search extension, it doesn't provide this feature